# How to Say "Thank You!"

Tags: discussion, comment, voting

I had some really nice comments, that were, to my opinion, more than great. They inspired new insight (or questions I posted).

I thought about, doing more than just upvoting their comments (and getting them closer to a Pundit badge), by upvoting a random question/answer.

Would this be ok, or can I do something else?

**EDIT:** By the way, I'd like to say "Thank you" to all people, contributing to this ever-so-cool web page.

Comment: I would say that upvotes (or downvotes) of a question/answer should be based on the content of that question/answer, not on any particular good (or ill) will that you may feel for the questioner/answerer.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So saying "Thanks" as another comment plus upvoting their comment is all I do. Thanks (and no random upvote for you. And because it's you, I can't resist to say, that you would hardly notice $+0.01\%$ (no offense) ).

Comment: You "can" do whatever you want (up to a limit); if you start upvoting a bunch of answers for someone, there's a chance the software will flag it as suspicious and take it away. But I had already [commented on the kind of behaviour you are suggesting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/strange-sequence-of-upvotes) (though perhaps more extreme than you were envisioning).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I can, but I'm happy that I asked to know what I should.

Comment: Not much point in upvoting people's other questions and answers, because reputation is useless anyway. I thought we established that with your previous question. :)

Comment: @RahulNarain Did I? I'm still hunting for the gifts (and the time travel worm hole of course :).

Comment: If you can work out the person's postal address, you can always send some flowers or chocolates or a bottle of 12 year old Scotch.

Comment: @Gerry: now you are just trying to get Asaf involved in this conversation, huh? `:-)`

Comment: @Willie: You owe me a *full* bottle of Glenfiddich Snow Phoenix. Where is it? $$\stackrel{\stackrel{\small\diagdown\ \diagup}{\bullet\quad\bullet}}{\huge\frown}$$

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always leave a comment below saying "That's a great comment which has improved my life. Everyone should vote it up!" If you don't overuse this, I bet that will got the commenter a good dozen upvotes, which will be a pretty nice thank you.

Comment: +1 Yes, this feels right. Vote up, folks!

Comment: A good idea, but I doubt it would actually generate too many upvotes. It's also not much of a thank-you.

Answer (score 8):

You can ask commenter to provide his comment as answer (may be hint as answer) and then bring him bounty(this also shows you are generous).